# How well does "insulating paint" insulate (if at all)?

Tags: consumer-products

Some manufacturers make big claims for insulating paint.

For example, [Thermilate](http://thermilate.com/) is claimed to be capable of:

> reducing energy-loss through walls and ceilings by up to 25% with just two coats.

I'm no physicist but it seems like snake oil to me.  Having worked with conventional insulation, I can't see how it could work.

Are there any independent studies on the subject?

Comment: Needs a notable claim, is this the paint you're referring to - http://thermilate.com/

Comment: The thermilate.com web site claims the paint "reduces energy-loss through walls and ceilings by up to 25% with just two coats."  Does such a claim only pertain to thermal radiation (which might be measurable with an IR camera) or does it also include, say, convection (air exchange)?

Comment: It will work in prinicial http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulative_paint  "Exacty how well it works is debatable"  http://homerenovations.about.com/od/houseexteriorframework/a/artinsulpaint.htm

Comment: @Tom77 : Claims like "reduces energy-loss through walls and ceilings by up to 25%" are typical of the claims made by manufacturers ("Up To" being the important phrase). Conversely, I have seen posts indicating that it has no effect at all. I guess what I was looking for was more detail - perhaps details of a test where temperature and humidity readings were taken over a significant period of time (At least a few hours) both inside and outside a room before and after the thermal paint was applied. This would give a better idea of what (if anything) the paint actually does.

Comment: What I have heard about these paints is that they are worthless if you expect to be able to paint a piece of plywood and have an R7 insulation, but they are a cost effective solution compared to replacing existing insulation.

Comment: @tofarr: Please tell us where you are getting those claims. Who is making the claim? Name the manufacturer or retailer. Where are they making the claims? Link to the site, or explain where you saw it. What are their claims, word-for-word? (Not "typical", but actual claims.)

Comment: Aerogel only need to be about blanket thickness to be able to withstand a flame thrower burning at 1700F (900C) and keep the other side safe to the touch, and the claim that NASA developed a similar technology [seems to be true](http://spinoff.nasa.gov/spinoff2003/er_4.html). However, I don't see how the technology could prevent convection, so I guess the claim is plausible if it is measuring only heat exchange through conduction and/or radiation.

Comment: @Oddthinking : I have updated the question to provide a specific claim.